# RoR - displaying separate error message s for form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, forms

How can i display the validation error messages just below the form field rather than showing all messages at the top of the page.

My Rails version is **Rails 3.0.0**

I have a table name category with fields id, title and description.
My model class is

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :title, :message => "Title already exist"
  validates_presence_of :title, :description => "Cannot be blank"
end
```

Controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
     @category = Category.new(params[:category])
     @category.created = Time.now
     @category.modified = Time.now
     respond_to do |format|
       if @category.save
         @category_last=Category.last
           format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'categories', :action => 'show', :id => @category_last.id }
       else
          #format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'categories', :action => 'new' } 
        end
     end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

end
```

and View

```
<div id="newCategory" class='page add'>
    <div class='screenTitle'>New Category</div>
    <div class='form_wrapper'>
        <%= form_tag :action=>'create' %>
            <div class='field_wrapper'>
                <div class='field_label'>
                    Title 
                </div>
                <div class='field_input'>
                    <%= text_area(:category, :description, :class=>'') %>
                </div>
                <div class='clearfix'>&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class='field_wrapper'>
                <div class='field_label'>
                    Title 
                </div>
                <div class='field_input'>
                    <%= text_field(:category, :title, :class=>'') %>
                </div>
                <div class='clearfix'>&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class='field_wrapper'>
                <div class='field_submit'>
                    <%= submit_tag "Submit", :type => "submit", :class => "submit" %>
                </div>
                <div class='clearfix'>&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
         </form>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
        <ul>
            <li><%= link_to 'List Categoris', root_url+'categories' %></li>
        </ul>
        <div class='clearfix'>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this. Use an empty model in the action :new like this:

```
def new
  @category = Category.new
end
```

And then use form_for instead of form_tag like this:

```
<%= form_for @category, :action=>'create' do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field(:title, :class=>'') %>
```

And then in the action :create I would try this:

```
if @category.save
  # redirect if you want to
else
  render :action => :new
end
```

That way, if the creation fails for some reason, the controller will render the template for :new but still use the failed @category object in the form_for helper. And you can always access the error messages of a model with @category.errors.on(:title)

So add the following to the view where you want the error message displayed:

```
<%= @category.errors.on(:title) unless @category.errors.on(:title).nil? %>
```

Comment: When i tried `<%= form_for @category :action=>'create' do |f| %>` i'm getting `RuntimeError in CategoriesController#new :attributes cannot be blank`

Comment: Sorry, a little typo from my side. Missed a comma. It should of course be <%= form_for @category, :action=>'create' do |f| %> And now that I think about it, you probably don't even need the :action hash. Try <%= form_for @category do |f| %>

Comment: i already corrected that syntax, actually the issue is not with the form_for tag, it is with the `@category = Category.new` statement in the new method in the controller, when i comment this line error is no longer displayed. What i'm wrong here..?

Comment: ` @category = Category.new` is not working if any validation rule defined in model

Comment: That seems really strange. The initialize method of ActiveRecord::Base does not require any parameters that I know. Can you see from the logs exactly which class and method actually throws the error? Cause the only thing I can think of right now is if you have something in your Category model that somehow does not work with an empty record.

Comment: Thanks DanneManne, there was an error in the model file `validates_presence_of :title, :description => "Cannot be blank"` should be ` validates_presence_of :title, :description, :message => "Cannot be blank"`

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. Hate those mistakes that only throws errors that seem unrelated :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic).  Lots of awesome stuff in there and does error by field very nicely.